# How do I extract a specific part of a string with NSRegularExpression?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Say I have a bunch of different strings:

```
"http://website.com/283/comments/einp43/2398/32/34/23/4/4"
"http://website.com/23283/l34/comments/inhd3/3928/3/2/3"
"http://website.com/pics/283/comments/en43/a89st/389238/a823/"
"http://website.com/pics/hd/283/comments/as87/asd7j/3"
```

And I always want the portion that follows `comments/` which is a valuable ID. But I don't want the comments part, I just want the ID.

How do I isolate/extract that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the website name is stored as an `NSString` called `websiteName`:

```
NSArray *components = [websiteName componentsSeparatedByString:@"comments/"];  
NSString *valuableID = [components lastObject];
```

(Edit: I didn't notice the mention of `NSRegularExpression` in the title until after posting this answer, but I don't think regex is necessary in this case since you're looking for a single constant string and have no need for complex pattern recognition.)

Comment: Wow, that's a really clever solution.

Comment: @DougSmith Thanks :) I'd think this is a pretty standard way to go about it though

Comment: @DougSmith Didn't notice your mention of regex in the title until now... I don't think regex is really necessary in this case since you're looking for a constant string and not a pattern.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Whoopsies. Must be bedtime. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regex, try this code

```
NSString *string = @"http://website.com/23283/l34/comments/inhd3/3928/3/2/3";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/comments/([^/]*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *subStr = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSLog(@"commentId = %@", subStr);
}];
```

output:

```
commentId = inhd3
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think he wants "inhd3/3928/3/2/3".